# Running Sqoop demo. NoHostAvailableException

Tags: mysql, cassandra, sqoop, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am running the Sqoop demo from the DataStax Enterprise 5.0 and i have followed every instruction and they seem to work fine. But when i run the import from the sql to cql i get the exception NoHostAvailableException. Please i need help. Thanks

This is my import options:

```
cql-import
--table
npa_nxx
--cassandra-keyspace
npa_nxx 
--cassandra-table
npa_nxx_data
--cassandra-column-mapping
npa:npa,nxx:nxx,latitude:lat,longitude:lon,state:state,city:city
--connect
jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/npa_nxx_demo
--username
root 
--password
xxxx
--cassandra-host 
127.0.0.1
```

After i run this i get this errors (image[Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrA0M.png))

Comment: instead of `127.0.0.1` use hostname: you can get hostname by this command: ` hostname -f`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `127.0.0.1` use hostname: you can get hostname by this command: `hostname -f`